# Python - socket server receives more data than I sent

Tags: python, sockets

I made an app to send to python socket the message "Oleft" when i tilt the phone but the result on console is like:

> connection from('192.168.0.101', 33313)
>   b'Oleft'
>   b'OleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleft'
>   b'Oleft'
>   b'OrightOrightOrightOright'
>   b'OleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOrightOrightOrightOrightOrightOrightOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleft'
>   b'OleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleft'
>   b'OleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleft'
>   b'OleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleftOleft'
>   b'OleftOleft'

It has no way to receive only an b'Oleft' ?

wgremote.py

```
import socket

class WGRemote:

    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.host = socket.gethostname()
        self.port = 10000
        self.received = None

    def connect(self):
        global c, addr
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.sock.listen(5)
        c, addr = self.sock.accept()
        print('connection from' + str(addr))

    def setMode(self,mode):
        sent = c.send(mode.encode("utf-8"))

    def receive(self):
        self.received = c.recv(1024)
        return self.received

    def close(self):
        c.close
```

testApp.py

```
import socket
import sys
from wgremote import WGRemote

remote = WGRemote()
remote.connect()
remote.setMode('orient')
while True:
    data = remote.receive()
    print(data)
```

Comment: I see no problem with this. You sent this string, and the server received it.

Comment: It has no way to receive only one b'Oleft'

Comment: Exactly. TCP protocol is a stream of bytes, not messages. It doesn't know you wanted to send these bytes separately. It's up to you to interpret them. Add a "\n" character to the string you send, and `receive` until "\n".

Comment: This worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because, You wrote print(data) in the while loop :)

```html
while True:
    data = remote.receive()
    print(data)
```

If you want to receive only an b'Oleft you can make a filter :

```html
count = 0
while True:
  data = remote.receive()
  if data == "b'Oleft":
    if count < 1:
      count = count + 1
      print(data)
```

Or you must send the only an b'Oleft :)